# Datatable's row click call javascript function using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Table contains 2 columns. each column have form elements like text box and dropdown box. what i want is , when i click the row i have to call javascript function. My problem is, when i enter value in textbox or select value from dropdown that time also javascript function has called. How to prevent this. i dont want to fire the javascript function when entering text box and select the value from dropdown.

```
jQuery("#testParam tbody tr").on("click", function(event) {
        var position = paramTable.fnGetPosition(this); // getting the clicked row position
        //alert(position);
        createTable();
    });

function createTable(){
     alert("clicked");
}

<table id="testParam">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="no-sort">
                Name
            </th>

            <th class="no-sort">
                Type
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="paramRow1">

            <td><g:textField name="name1" id="name1" required="" value="${testName}" /></td>

            <td><g:select name="type1" noSelection="['':'-Select-']"
                    id="type1"
                    from="${testParameterInstance?.constraints?.type?.inList}"
                    required="" value="${testParameterInstance?.type}"
                    valueMessagePrefix="testParameter.type"  /></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
$('#name1,#type1').on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Happy Coding :)